# Word for "extensively written about"

Tags: single-word-requests

What is one word for "extensively researched and written about"? Not famous in the sense of "known" or "talked about" but specifically "written" about in a positive way.

"....and one became highly acclaimed and (extensively written about), but was 'kept a secret' because of the colour of his skin…."

Comment: Well-documented?

Comment: Thank you. I thought of that (extensively documented) but wondered whether there was another/better word. Thank you so much!

Comment: How does one become highly acclaimed and written about and at the same time be kept a secret?

Comment: @Jim -"[Pseudonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudonym) are most usually adopted to hide an individual's real identity, as with writers' pen names, graffiti artists' tags, resistance fighters' or terrorists' *noms de guerre*, and computer hackers' handles. Actors, musicians, and other performers sometimes use stage names, for example, to mask their ethnic backgrounds."

Comment: @Mazura - well ok. But if that’s what’s being used in OP’s instance then it is extremely misleading.  In that case it is the author’s *work* that is highly acclaimed while the author’s [real] *identity* is kept secret.  ***one*** can’t be used to refer to both in the same sentence.

Comment: You can talk about being “***well covered***” in the literature or journals or the [news]papers or  wherever this writing appears.

Comment: Your phrase *highly acclaimed* already carries much of the sense of *extensively written about in a positive manner*. "Acclaimed" relates to positive reviews. "Highly" relates more to the extent of the manner than to the number of reviews, but *widely acclaimed* would give it the sense you're after.

Answer (score 1):

**review** /rəˈvyo͞o/ verb

> write a critical appraisal of (a book, play, movie, etc.) for publication in a newspaper or magazine. –[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=reviewed%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

"....and one became highly acclaimed and *reviewed*, but was 'kept a secret' because of the colour of his skin…."

*was reviewed (extensively)*

*was subject to review (at length)*

*highly acclaimed upon review* / *reviewed with high acclaim*

---

Those reviews could then, themselves, be further *dissected*.

**dissect** /dəˈsekt,dīˈsekt/ verb

> analyze (something) in minute detail. *"novels that dissect our obsession with cities and urban angst"* –[Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=dissected%20definition)

*and was dissected at length...*
*was extensively dissected...*
*was subject to extensive dissection...*

---

Here's the next runner up:

**exposition** (ˌɛk spəˈzɪʃ ən) noun

> 3. a detailed statement or explanation; explanatory treatise. –[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exposition)

Even when his work was subjected to such high acclaim in its reviews (ones that had dissected it so well, that they themselves became expositions), still he felt it necessary to use a pseudonym.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I’m confused.  I saw this question yesterday,
and I thought ***acclaimed*** would make a good answer. 
It would have been helpful if you had explained why “acclaimed”
*isn’t* the word you’re looking for. 
And are you expecting to find a single word
that encompasses the compound meaning of “extensively researched
and written about but was ‘kept a secret’ because of the color of his skin”,
or are you looking for a word that means only
“extensively researched and written about”? 
(And why does your sample sentence have “one” as the subject,
rather than just a person’s name?)

OK, I have some other suggestions:

***[celebrated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/celebrated):***

> widely known and often referred to

***[storied](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/storied):***

> having an interesting history : celebrated in story or history
>   <a *storied* institution>

If the reports have been embellished, consider ***[fabled](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fabled):***

> told about in old stories

or ***[legendary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legendary):***

> very famous or well-known

although beware that these (particularly ***fabled***)
may be interpreted to mean that the person is fictitious.

Answer (score -2):

[Erudite](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/erudite):  having or showing knowledge that is gained by studying :  possessing or displaying erudition

Comment: The reason you received a downvote here is probably that a reviewer felt that the suggested word, as defined, doesn't match the sense that the original question describes. With regard to form and presentation, however, your answer is actually above average for a SWR response, since it provides both a definition of the suggested word and a link to the source of that definition (Merriam-Webster Online). The only additional information you might include is a brief explanation of why the suggested word, as defined, meets the questioner's needs.